# Model derivative API affecting v6 viewer?

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Seems something changed with the recent updates to the model derivative api affecting the v6 viewer? When I upload this project to the API and view it in the viewer version 6.6.4 I get the following images. The same exact project looks just fine in Revit 2020. Is there a possibility a bug was introduced in the latest updates to the API that would affect older versions (6.6.4) of the viewer?

[API image...notice the hardware placed incorrectly everywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeRGv.png)

[Revit 2020 image...everything placed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5yNQ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any change in the Model Derivative service that could be causing this. This could be something specific to the Revit model. Can you repro the issue with other Revit models as well? When you mention the viewer version 6.6.4, have you also tried loading the model in version 7.*? Is the model ok there?

Comment: Since this seems to be a very specific issue, consider sharing the model with us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`. We can try and debug the issue on our end (will not share the file with anyone outside of the company), and if needed, have the Model Derivative team look at the file as well.